# String match across chunks in a network stream

Tags: algorithm, replace, network-programming, buffer, string-matching

I have to handle a situation where the incoming data from a server needs to be searched through for a string and then replaced with another string (without buffering the data as far as possible.)

The incoming data can be in multiple chunks. Thus, there is a chance that a given string may be split across multiple chunks. For example, if the string is 'abc', the chunks can be chunk 1: 'aaab' & chunk 2 : 'cbbb'. Then after matching 'a' in the first chunk, we will have to wait  to see if there is a match for 'b' in the next chunk. This means that now we will have to start buffering the first chunk . Or, at least, the letters in the first chunk that matched need to be buffered until we can figure out if the second chunk contains the remainder of the string.

If it does not, then we will have to return to the first chunk and restart matching from the letter b.

Given the application constraints, buffering needs to be avoided as much as possible.
Are there ways to achieve this with minimal buffering? To me, this appears to be a generic enough problem that would be faced in several situations but unfortunately, I have not been able to find any solution or a direction after searching.

Comment: Is there some other boundary except the chunks? Can a string span multiple chunks?

Comment: No, there is no boundary except the length of the message that will be sent before the actual message is being sent. Yes, a string can span multiple chunks. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the pattern to be searched can be completely in one chunk or it can be span across two or more chunks depending on pattern and chunk size. In case when pattern is in two chunks, then we need to track all pattern prefixes found in 1st chuck (as suffixes) and then search corresponding pattern suffixes in 2nd chunk (as prefixes).
Here multiple pattern searching may be needed on each chunk and suffix tree could be used here.
When we receive a new chuck, we already know all the pattern to be searched on that. We can make suffix tree of that chunk, do all the search, process as needed and move to the next chunk and do the same thing on that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at finite state machines. [Here's](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960222.html) a text with some examples.

Say you want to detect the pattern "ABCD". In that case, you'd have five states:

1. No Character has been found
2. A has been found
3. AB has been found
4. ABC has been found
5. ABCD has been found

The machine itself would look something like this:

```
           IN:A         IN:B          IN:C          IN:D
STATE_NONE ---> STATE_A ---> STATE_AB ---> STATE_ABC ---> STATE_ABCD
^     |               |            |             |             
|     |else           |else        |else         |
|     v               v            v             v
|-----<---------------<------------<-------------<
```

The machine stats off at STATE_NONE and processes the input one char at a time. If for example the current state is STATE_A and B arrives, then we move to STATE_AB. But it at STATE_A we get "C", the we move to STATE_NONE. For the detection, at each step, you only need to store the current state of the machine. But since you also want to replace the detected pattern, at each state you'd have to store the last few bytes that brought you from STATE_NONE to the current state.

EDIT:

My state machine is missing a few state transitions. From STATE_AB, if an "A" arrives, we have to go back to STATE_A, not STATE_NONE. The same goes for states A, ABC and ABCD - if an A arrives, go back to STATE_A. Otherwise, you'd miss patterns such as "ABCABCD".

Comment: Thanks for the response. The procedure that you described is valid for matching and replacing a string. The problem in question has an added issue of minimizing the buffering. I am seeking standard solutions, if any, for this issue.

Comment: I mentioned the buffering in my answer. At state A, you have to buffer 1 character (which is A), At state AB, the last two (which are AB). At state ABC, the last three (which are ABC) etc. So the maximum buffering is the length of your pattern, which is the lower bound on the required buffering anyway if you need to replace the whole pattern. So the buffering is minimal.